# How can we create a ssh connection on Android?

Tags: java, android, ssh

I am currently developing an android application and I would like the opportunity to connect with ssh.

The open source implementation **[ConnectBot](http://code.google.com/p/connectbot/.)** can do this but I find the overly complex solution.

Nevertheless, I would like to know if someone does not have a simple solution.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into JSch? A quick google shows a few examples of JSch being used in an Android app.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it seems interesting!